# What default system tables are available on Informix 9.53C1?

Tags: database, schema, informix, catalog, data-dictionary

I'm looking for the data dictionary for Informix 9.53C1 system tables/catalog.

I've found a couple sites that show some of these tables, but I couldn't find a full, comprehensive list of all system tables and their contents.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10528_01/apc.htm#634419

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/zones/informix/library/techarticle/0305parker/0305parker.html

I'm looking for a list of all the the default system tables built into Informix.  Having a list of all these tables' fields would also help greatly, but as long as I have the table names, I can go fishing for their fields myself.

Example:

`informix.systables` is a detailed listing of all tables

`informix.syscolumns` is a detailed listing of all columns

---

[Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), help me ***again*** please!

Comment: Which version of the server is confusing you with the tag 9.53?  There's an oddity that 9.xx version numbers are used in a couple of places because 1x.xx would compare earlier than 9.xx (you're right, it is pathetic, or at least apathetic; what a difference one letter makes!). You can find the meanings of the system catalog tables in the documentation at [IDS 11.70 Info Centre](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp).  Things don't change much; witness the continued presence of `syssynonyms` which was made obsolete by `syssyntable` in version 4.00 over 20 years ago.

Comment: Incidentally, there are no system tables that are 'non-default'; the system catalog tables are always all present.  Some of the tables in the special databases (sysmaster in particular; sysadmin, sysuser, syscdr, sysutil too) have a 'sys' prefix, but the tabid is larger than 99.  They do not describe the database like the system catalog tables do.  They are simply specially named tables that happen to start with the 'sys' prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, at the very least, these tables are all default system tables:

```
sysaggregates
sysams
sysattrtypes
sysblobs
syscasts
syschecks
syscolattr
syscolattribs
syscolauth
syscoldepend
syscolperm
syscolumns
sysconstraints
sysdefaults
sysdepend
sysdirectives
sysdistrib
sysdomains
syserrors
sysextcols
sysextdfiles
sysexternal
sysfragauth
sysfragments
sysindexes
sysindices
sysinherits
syslangauth
syslogmap
sysobjstate
sysopclasses
sysopclstr
sysprocauth
sysprocbody
sysproccolumns
sysprocedures
sysprocperm
sysprocplan
sysreferences
sysroleauth
sysroutinelangs
sysseclabelauth
sysseclabelcomponentelements
sysseclabelcomponents
sysseclabelnames
sysseclabels
syssecpolicies
syssecpolicycomponents
syssecpolicyexemptions
syssequences
syssurrogateauth
syssynonyms
systabamdata
systabauth
systables
systabperm
systraceclasses
systracemsgs
systrigbody
systriggers
sysusers
sysviews
sysviolations
sysxadatasources
sysxasourcetypes
sysxtddesc
sysxtdtypeauth
sysxtdtypes
```

Comment: At the moment, all system catalog tables have `tabid < 100`.  There are not all that many slots open still in the range 1..99, but there are a few.  Some entries in `systables` within this range are views, and a few are not really tables at all.  Look at the `tabtype` column for some more information.

Comment: ok, thanks - good to know.  I ended up doing a `select first 1 *` for all of these to take a peek in them and noticed a lot were empty. Are they some sort of transaction tables?

Comment: Pulling names at random: sysdomains is unused (still-born feature); sysinherits is only used if you have table hierarchies; syscolauth is only used if you grant column-specific SELECT or UPDATE privileges; sysopclstr is only used if you're using the Optical feature (and you aren't); the syssec* tables are populated if you're using LBAC; sysviolations is only used if you're using violations tables (START/STOP VIOLATIONS); etc.  So, it is normal for many of the system catalog tables to be empty.  I have 35 empty tables or views with tabid < 100 in an 11.70.FC2 database (and 32 non-empty ones!).